# Laravel Routing with javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, routes

I have a function which returns a parameter from a table when the user clicks. The data is pulled in via ajax and that is why I am using javascript.

My function is simply:

```
<script>
 function selectItem(id)
    {
       alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

What I want is to have a passing to a URL which will pass the id to the lavavel route (rather than the alert which was simply checking the parameter passed), something like

```
{{ URL('quotations/p_customerselected/{id}') }}
```

I did try

```
{{ URL('quotations/p_customerselected/') }} + id;
```

but threw an error.

Comment: Please provide more of you code

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your controller name is QuotationController and controller function name is viewcustomer.

In web.php, give your route a name like

```
Route::post('/quotations/p_customerselected/{id}', 'QuotationController@viewcustomer')->name('quotations.p_customerselected');
```

Now in Javascript:

```
<script>
 function selectItem(cust_id)
 {
   var url = '{{ route("quotations.p_customerselected", ":id") }}';
   url = url.replace(':id', cust_id);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it a different (and probably ineligant!) way. On the datatable I added:

```
{"targets": 0,
                        "data": 'id',
                        render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            var id = full['DT_RowId'].substring(4).trim();
                            var url = "{{ URL('quotations/p_customerselected/') }}" +"/" + id;
                            return '<a href="' + url + '"><span style="color: darkblue" title="select">' + full['DT_RowId'].substring(4).trim() +'</span></a>'
                        } 
                    }
```

It works though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that I understand correctly, but if you want pass param to url you can use array to bind them. 
Something like this

```
{{ url('quotations/p_customerselected}', [$id]) }}
```

**UPD**

if you generate your js code in view, you must insert generated url in quotes.

```
"{{ url('quotations/p_customerselected}') }}" +  id
```

Comment: The id in question comes from the incoming parameter of a java script function

Comment: If I understand correctly, you generate your js code in view. Is't it?

Comment: To make it clear, I have a datatable with an ajax load and the incoming id is given from an onClck event so I have a javascript function to catch it. I want now to go to a route with the id passed to the route.