post id for data deletion using ajax showing missing required parameters in controller route
I am trying to delete data via datatable delete button. But I am getting error.
I have created route as::
Route::resource('dealers', DealerController::class);

My controller function::
public function destroy($id ): JsonResponse
    {
        // removed the code block
    }

output of php artisan route:list
DELETE          dealers/{dealer} ........... dealers.destroy › Dealers\DealerController@destroy

ajax code block of blade php page
$(document).on('click','.deleteProduct', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var id = $(this).data("id");
 confirm("Are You sure want to delete?");
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:  "{{ route('dealers.destroy') }}"+'/'+id,
        //  data: data,
        //  dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
          var oTable = $('#dealerTabel').dataTable();
          oTable.fnDraw(false);
         },
         error: function (data) {
             console.log('Error:', data);
         }
     });

when I try to load the page it's showing error as::
Missing required parameter for [Route: dealers.destroy] [URI: dealers/{dealer}] [Missing parameter: dealer].


Check the final URL the AJAX request is actually sending to. Presumably it's not in the format Laravel is expecting

You need to check the result of your confirm("Are You sure want to delete?"); line. No matter what the user clicks, you will send the delete ajax.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634285/laravel-4-pass-a-variable-to-route-in-javascript, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526364/how-can-i-generate-a-route-in-laravel-with-a-placeholder-replaceable-value-for-u, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44102058/laravel-routing-with-javascript-parameter

The reason you're having a hard time is that your mixing your js scope and your php scope.
First, the php route() command requires the id in order to create the route, so when you have {{ route('dealers.destroy') }}, the route command fails. You would have to specify an id as in {{ route('dealers.destroy', 1) }}
Second, your php is run long before the js is run, so the php would not have the php variable available to it.
One option is to hard code the route into the JS. Not a great idea, but not terrible.
 $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:  "/dealers/"+id,
         data: {"_method":"DELETE"},
     });

Another, slightly more robust method is to put a placeholder in the url and replace it later.
const url = "{{ route('dealers.destroy','____') }}".replace('____', id);


Thank you for your explicit reply. I didn't get some of your points. you're having a hard time is that your mixing your js scope and your php scope Please explain on this more. And your php is run long before the js is run, so the php would not have the php variable available to it. how PHP code is running before ajax request?

The php code (i.e. the blade syntax in the {{}}) is rendering on the server side before the js code is compiled. So, you can't use a js variable (id) within the php code because it doesn't exist yet. You can do it the other way around, by using a php variable in the js.
